# cygwin /usr/bin/install cannot change permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, cygwin, chmod, chown

When I run `/usr/bin/install`, I get permissions errors:

```
bifrost ~ 857# groups
None Local account and member of Administrators group tsysadm Administrators Users NETWORK Authenticated Users This Organization Local account CurrentSession NTLM Authentication High Mandatory Level
bifrost ~ 858# install -d -C -v -o ohm -g tsysadm -m 770 /tmp/foo
install: creating directory '/tmp/foo'
install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/tmp/foo’: Permission denied
bifrost ~ 859# mkpasswd -l |grep ohm
ohm:*:197611:197121:U-BIFROST\ohm,S-1-5-21-3492648455-385089027-368225528-1003:/home/ohm:/bin/bash
bifrost ~ 860# mkgroup -l |grep tsysadm
tsysadm:S-1-5-21-3492648455-385089027-368225528-1004:197612:
bifrost ~ 861# ll -d /tmp/foo
drwx------ 1 ohm tsysadm 0 Sep 27 22:38 /tmp/foo/
bifrost ~ 862# uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19044 bifrost 3.3.6-341.x86_64 2022-09-05 11:15 UTC x86_64 Cygwin
bifrost ~ 865# cd /tmp
bifrost /tmp 1013# ll -d foo
drwx------ 1 ohm tsysadm 0 Sep 27 22:38 foo/
bifrost /tmp 1014# chown bennett foo
bifrost /tmp 1015# ll -d foo
drwx------ 1 bennett tsysadm 0 Sep 27 22:38 foo/
bifrost /tmp 1016# chmod 775 foo
bifrost /tmp 1017# ll -d foo
drwxrwxr-x 1 bennett tsysadm 0 Sep 27 22:38 foo/
bifrost /tmp 1018#
```

So it looks like it worked, except `$?` is 1, so `make` fails.

Curiously, `chown` works like one would expect.

Is this a failure on my part?

I tried to `strace` it, but I'm way out of my depth on Windows permissions/rights.

Comment: Are you running this in an "elevated" shell? Changing file ownership is a privileged operation on Windows just as on Linux.

Comment: Yeah.  As I showed in the `groups` command I have `Administrators` and `Authentication High Mandatory Level`.  I don't know which one of these gets permission to `chown`, but `/usr/bin/chown` works.

Comment: I added some `chown` and `chmod` lines.